# Can this code be improved? (testing if a variable is set)

Tags: php

```
if (!is_null($_GET[SH]))
{

    //Bla bla bla bla you don't need to look
    $data=$_GET[SH]. " - " . date("c");
    putTotalData($filename."complete.txt",$_GET[SH]);
    putData($filename.".txt", $data);
}
```

Basically I am testing if $_GET[SH] is set or not. However, if I do it this way, I got a warning saying that it's not set. And then the code works otherwise just fine.

So is this the way to do it? Is there  a way to test if an associative array has a particular key?

Comment: Use `if (!empty($_GET[SH]))` Also are you sure `SH` is a constant?!

Comment: Also don't use user input values directly in file system interactions.

Comment: As stated. `SH` is considered/treated as a constant. You would want to use `$_GET['SH']` - *"(testing if a variable is set)"* - Use just that then, `isset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_null` checks whether a value is of type `null` (analogous to `is_int`, `is_string` etc.). If you're passing a variable in, this variable must exist. If it does not, you'll get a warning.

`isset` is a language construct which explicitly can handle variables which do not exist. That's its purpose. Replace `is_null` with `isset`.

Coincidentally, `$_GET` parameters can never be `null`, at worst they're an empty string. Otherwise the parameter doesn't exist at all. And that's what you're seeing: nonexistent variables trigger a warning and are then substituted by the value `null` (because what else could it be?).

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `isset` function like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['sh'])) { /* your code */ } else { /* your code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset($var)`, however, I usually want a default value, and so I do this:

```
$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

`empty` checks if the var is set and empty ('', 0, false, null)

```
if(!empty($_GET['SH'])) {
    //something
}
```